# How do i list out all related data in mysqli table column one after the other

Tags: php, mysqli, foreach

How do i list out all related data in mysqli database one after the other?
I tried these code below. It outputs unknown result:

```
<?php
    include_once "init.php";
    $sqli = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM books WHERE book='1905515'");
    $productCount = mysqli_num_rows($sqli);
    if ($productCount > 0) {
        while($fow = mysqli_fetch_array($sqli)){
            foreach ($fow as $item) {
                $id = $item['item_name'];
            }
        }
    }
    echo '' . $id . '';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

when you call `echo '' . $id . '';` $id doesn't exist anymore because $id exists only in foreach scope.

Try this :

```
include_once "init.php";
$sqli = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM books WHERE book='1905515'");
$productCount = mysqli_num_rows($sqli);
if ($productCount > 0) {
    while($fow = mysqli_fetch_array($sqli)){
        echo '' . $fow['item_name'] . '';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: @S ébastientemprado Not working i need a better result as inserted in the database
include_once "init.php";
    $sqli = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM books WHERE book='1905515'");
    $productCount = mysqli_num_rows($sqli);
    if ($productCount > 0)
    {
    while($fow = mysqli_fetch_array($sqli)){
    foreach ($fow as $item) {
    $result_from_culumn = $item['item_name'];
    echo '' . $result_from_culumn . '';
    }
    }
    }
    
    ?>

Comment: All i get as output result is (34526352452552) so on instead my result should be (wap boy fan good) just as inserted in the table culumn do you see other solution? thanks

Comment: you want to insert the result in a column of the table?

Comment: No retrive.
 my point is that it do not returns a good result as (boy fan god ) as recorded in the table

Comment: What is the result of your sql query? See the documentation : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php
You don't need the `foreach`